# Reading a file and mapping values

Tags: c#

I found an implementation of a parallel coordinates application in c#. What I am trying to achieve is that I want to be able to read a CSV file and map the values and Labels onto the coordinates. The method mapping the values is assigning the values manually. Instead, I want those values to be read from the CSV file.

Here is the current method:

```
public void DataBind()
        {
            IList<DemoInfo> infos = new List<DemoInfo>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ObjectsCount; i++)
            {
                var x = new DemoInfo();
                x.X = m_Random.NextDouble() * 400 - 100;
                x.Y = m_Random.NextDouble() * 500 - 100;
                x.Z = m_Random.NextDouble() * 600 - 300;
                x.V = m_Random.NextDouble() * 800 - 100;
                x.K = 1.0;
                //x.M = i % 2 == 0 ? 1.0 : -20.0;
                x.M = i;
                x.Tag = i + 1;

                infos.Add(x);
            } 



var dataSource = new MultiDimensionalDataSource<DemoInfo>(infos, 6);
            dataSource.MapDimension(0, info => info.X);
            dataSource.MapDimension(1, info => info.Y);
            dataSource.MapDimension(2, info => info.Z);
            dataSource.MapDimension(3, info => info.V);
            dataSource.MapDimension(4, info => info.K);
            dataSource.MapDimension(5, info => info.M);

            //dataSource.MapDimensionToOpacity(0, 0.5);
            dataSource.MapTag(info => info.Tag);

            dataSource.Labels[0] = "X";
            dataSource.Labels[1] = "Y";
            dataSource.Labels[2] = "Z";
            dataSource.Labels[3] = "V";
            dataSource.Labels[4] = "K";
            dataSource.Labels[5] = "M";
            dataSource.HelperAxisLabel = "Helper axis";

            DataSource = dataSource;
        }
```

Here is some of the data in the CSV File:

```
SWW Institutions        Undergradutes       Postgraduates
University College      2085            250 
Metropolitan University 4715            1135
```

Would really appreciate your help !!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the CSV file?

Comment: @lcarus I have posted the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your CSV file is mapping to the DemoInfo class. Also, the example below is based on a CSV file, but your sample data is showing a TSV file. If it is a TSV file, just replace ',' with '/t'. Also, something watch out for is if any strings contain your delimiter, such as a SWW Institutions string like "Univeristy, Madison".

You can open the file to read the lines of text and split the line based on your delimiter.

```
using (var sr = File.OpenText(path))
{
  var line = string.Empty;
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    var dataPoints = line.Split(',');
    // Create Your Data Mappings Here
    // dataPoints[0]...
  }
}
```